# PHP edit mp4 file metadata to move headers to the start so stream starts from the beginning

Tags: php, metadata, mp4

I have a lot of mp4 files that need to be loaded completely by web player, for them to start playing. These mp4 files probably have their metadata not in the beginning, but in the end while encoded.

Is there a way to solve this issue by php? To move metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [qt-faststart](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/) ([google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt-faststart)) utility to tweak your MPEG-4 files. This utility moves the meta information from the end of file to the beginning. MPEG-4 files "fixed" by this utility start almost immediately without requiring the media player/plugins/flash based players to seek the end of file first.

Comment: Do you know how can I do it on fatcow.com shared hosting with php?

Comment: The utility is an executable file; it patches the video files by moving few bytes around. You must download the videos, patch them and upload them back. Another solution is to upload/build qt-faststart on server then use ssh or a PHP script to patch all videos.

Comment: I can't download so much videos. my hosting supports python but cgi. I don't have console ssh access or something like that. Also my hosting cannot execute scripts written in c, c++, visual basic, etc. Do you think I can do this by simple php, or python but (cgi python)?

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart) seems to use Python. I don't know if someone has created PHP version of this script.

Comment: I uploaded files in cgi-bin directory and when I executed setup.py it gave me error `The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.`

Comment: I don't think I can do it but thanks, `qt-faststart` is an answer. I don't know any python, i know php. And this approach that I tried to install this script you told me was probably very stupid. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use:

```
$qtConvRes = shell_exec("qt-faststart " . escapeshellcmd($ffmpegFullConv["fullNewFilename"]) . "-t.mp4 " . escapeshellcmd($ffmpegFullConv["fullNewFilename"]) . ".mp4");
```

try.